# Invoking a plugin after parallel step has completed for a stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline stage like so

```
stage('Unit Tests') {
      steps {
        parallel (
          "Jasmine": {
            sh 'gulp karma-tests-ci'
          },
           "Mocha": {
            sh 'gulp mocha-tests'
          }
        )
      }
    }
```

I would like to add a junit plugin call after the parallel step has completed, I tried

```
stage('Unit Tests') {
      steps {
        parallel (
          "Jasmine": {
            sh 'gulp karma-tests-ci'
          },
           "Mocha": {
            sh 'gulp mocha-tests'
          }
        )
        junit 'test/coverage/junit-coverage-results.xml'
      }
    }
```

But get the error:

```
WorkflowScript: 18: Invalid step "parallel" used - not allowed in this context - The parallel step can only be used as the only top-level step in a stages step block
```

Is there a way I can do this before progressing to the next stage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of writing, if you're using `parallel` in a `steps` block of a declarative pipeline, you can't use any other steps.

However, you can add a [`post` section](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) to your stage, so that the `junit` step is always run after successful test execution.  For example:

```java
stage('Unit Tests') {
  steps {
    parallel
      'Jasmine': {
        sh 'gulp karma-tests-ci'
      },
      'Mocha': {
        sh 'gulp mocha-tests'
      }
  }
  post {
    success {
      junit 'test/coverage/jasmine-results.xml'
      junit 'test/coverage/mocha-results.xml'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the way I ended up going. I happen to be using the Blue Ocean beta plugin and notice when the post steps are being run, there is no indication these are progressing in the UI. The Blue Ocean plugin just highlights the last step, in my case Jasmine\Mocha in green. It sits there for a while until the post step is done and then marks the entire run as succeeded. Is there a way to see that the post steps are in progress? Sorry this is probably a bit beyond the scope of the original question!

Comment: @mindparse Hmm, that seems surprising, since the `post` steps are still part of the `stage`. Good question! I'd [raise an issue](https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/#join-the-community) with the Blue Ocean folks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `steps` inside the parallel branches.

In groovy this should work:

```
stage ("test"){
    parallel(
        "Mocha": {
            node{
                sh 'gulp mocha-tests'
            }
        },
        "Jasmin": {
            node{
                sh 'gulp karma-tests-ci'
            }
        }
    )
    node{
        junit 'test/coverage/junit-coverage-results.xml'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I actually found using a post event after the parallel step was what i needed https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Reporting-test-results-and-storing-artifacts